# Parameters ? not working with python postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, parameters

I am using `python` with `postgres` and i am trying this simple query but its not working and i am not able to find why

```
con = psycopg2.connect(**config)


self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (id, age, year) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), ?, ?)", ('77', '44'))
```

I am getting this error

> > psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "," LINE 1:
> >     ...year) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), ?, ?)

EDIT

This is the error

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, age, year) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), %s, %s)
'6.65', '4955/1'

  File "off.py", line 80, in writeRows
    self.cursor.execute(query, values)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

CODE:

```
data = [('age', '6.65'), ('year', '4974/1'), . . ]
cols = ",".join(data.keys())
qmarks = ','.join(['%s' for s in data.keys()])
query = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, %s) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), %s)" % (cols,qmarks)
self.cursor.execute(query, values)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`psycopg2` uses `pyformat` param style:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> psycopg2.paramstyle
'pyformat'
```

Replace the parameter marker `?` with `%s`.

---

See [PEP 249 -- Python Database API Specification v2.0 - `paramstyle`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle).

Comment: I am getting syntax error like this `self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (id, age) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), %s", '44')
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` can you please write my code in `%s` style so that i know what else to chnage

Comment: @user3113427, The number of parameter markers and the length of parameters should match (parameters should be list or tuple): `self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (id, age, year) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), %s, %s)", ('77', '44'))`

Comment: Thanks for that. if i have `values = ('77', '44')` and `query = INSERT INTO mytable (id, age, year) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), %s, %s)` can i use `self.cursor.execute(query, values)` or thats wrong

Comment: @user3113427, It seems ok. BTW, Did you quote the query string? (`query = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, age, year) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), %s, %s)"`) If you got any error, show me the error.

Comment: I ahve quoted the query. i have added the error in my question , can you please have a look, i tried `self.cursor.execute(query, tuple(values))` as well but didn't work

Comment: @user3113427, You can use parameter markers only for parameters not for column name. In addition to that, if you want to insert multiple rows, use [`executemany`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany).

Comment: Thanks falsetru , i find the problem , the issue was that my `values` were comma separated string not list , that was causing the issue